# If $A \times B$ is finite, does it follow that $A$ and $B$ are finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem :** If $A \times  B$ is finite, does it follow that $A$ and $B$ are finite?

**Note :**  $A \times  B$ is the cartesian product. If $A \times  B$  is empty, we may not be able to say that If $A$ and $B$ are finite because one may be empty and the other may be infinite. An example of this case would be if $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $B=\emptyset$. Then, $A \times  B = \mathbb{R} \times \emptyset=\emptyset$. Note that this $\emptyset$ denotes empty set.
However, if $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty and $A \times  B$ is finite, then both $A$ and $B$ are finite.

**My Try :** Now I want to try to apply a **Corollary** which states

> Let $B$ be a nonempty set. Then the following are equivalent
>
> - $B$ is finite
> - There is a surjective function from a section of the positive integers onto $B$
> - There is an injective function from $B$ into a section of positive integers.

Now applying this Corollary from $(3)\Rightarrow (1)$. Suppose that $A \times  B$ is finite.

Then, there is an injective function: $f: A \times B \to S_n$ where $S_n$, denotes a set of positive integers less than $n$.

Let $B \neq \emptyset $. Then $f : A \times \{b\} \to S_n$, is an injective function for a fixed $b \in B$. Then changing the range of $f$ gives a bijection of $ A \times \{b\}$ with a subset of $S_n$. It then follows that $A$ is finite. Similarly, if $A\neq \emptyset$, then $B$ is finite.

Am I so far correct?

Comment: An easy hint: as long as $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, you should be able to find an injection $A\to A\times B$. (I'm implicitly assuming the axiom of choice; this is still true without, but things get marginally trickier there.)

Comment: Never post unsearchable images of text.  Show courtesy to your potential helpers by always typesetting your question in *MathJax*.

Answer (score 6):

No.

$A\times\varnothing$ and $\varnothing \times B$ are both finite (in fact, empty) for any sets $A$ and $B$.

But but in the case of nonempty $A$ and $B$, the answer is yes. That's because $|A\times B| = |A| \cdot |B|$.